# How to override tableView style in a subclass

Tags: swift, uitableview, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a superclass that is used in many places and its a just a class that conforms to tableView delegates.

```
    class SuperTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var tableView: UITableView = {

            let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)

            return tableView
        }()

    ... //more code

    }
```

I want to create a subclass that inherits from the SuperTableViewController but it should have a grouped style, I am not sure how to override the tableview style in the subclass:

```
    class SubClassController: SuperTableViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

     tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped) // this doesn't work
    }

    ... //more code

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a tableView style property in the `SuperTableViewController` as below and `override` in the subClasses. This way you don't have to initialize the whole `tableView` or register cells altogether in subClasses.

```
class SuperTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableViewStyle: UITableView.Style {
        return .plain
    }

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
         let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: self.tableViewStyle)
         return tableView
    }()
}

class SubClassController: SuperTableViewController {

    override var tableViewStyle: UITableView.Style {
        return .grouped
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you're inheriting `SuperTableViewController` as a `UIViewController` in `SubClassController`, so `SuperTableViewController` must be of type `UIViewController`.

```
class SuperTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        return tableView
    }()
}
```

Then in `SubClassController's` `viewDidLoad()` methods, you can simply se a new instance of `tableView` using `grouped` `style`, i.e.

```
class SubClassController: SuperTableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but I get errors : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SimpleCard - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Have you searched this issue? It is regarding not registering the `UITableViewCell `that you might be using in the `tableView`.